# Can you implement a new type as for the input of a function in C, cs50

Tags: c, types, typedef, cs50

I was in the making of a small program for a phonebook but i can't get my input to work for my function called "search" the variable that I am having trouble with is of type "person" witch I just created (a list of 2 array)

The problem that is given to me is when I compile my code, it says that the type person is not a type but I have made a new type with typedef.

I'm not looking for optimization just the why my type is not accepted as a type for the var in the input of my function

There is the code :

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// new type for storing list of name and phone numbers.
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    string number;
}
person;

void search(int count, person people[]);

int main(void)
{
    // get the user input for how many person you want
    int person_count = get_int("How many person is there? : ");
    
    // create people and the length of the array
    person people[person_count];

    // make the repertoire for each person on the list 
    for (int i = 0; i < person_count; i++)
    {
        // get user input for each person
        people[i].name = get_string("Your name : ");
        people[i].number = get_string("Your number : ");

        printf("\n");
    }

    search(person_count, people);
}

// new function "search"
void search(int count, person people[])
{
    int repeat = 0;

    // get user input for his search
    string name_search = get_string("Your search : ");

    // iterate for every person on the list 
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(people[j].name, name_search) == 0)
        {
            printf("This is the phone number of %s\n", people[j].name);
            printf("%s\n", people[j].number);
            return
        }
    }
    else
    {
        repeat = 1;
    }

    // if not found 
    printf("%s, is not in our repertoire.\n", name_search);

    if (repeat == 1)
    {

        // asking if they want to search it again
        string try_again = get_string("Would you like to search for a other person? (Y/N) : ");

        if (strcmp(try_again, "Yes") == 0 || strcmp(try_again, "yes") == 0 || (int) try_again == 89 || (int) try_again == 121)
        {
            sreach(count, people);
        }
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Please only add one language tag that is respective to your code.

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yBlvUHyg6574Wtzv) after adding some tweaks to run online environment without `cs50.h`. Instead of reproducing, some other errors are found: missing semicolon, invalid use of `else`, and use of undeclared `sreach`. What compiler are you using? Is code posted here your real code?

Comment: Yes it is my code and my compiler is clang. my ide is cs50 ide. and yes it is giving me more error than what I reported but I'm only focusing on this one for now. And I can't seem to see where I'm missing a semicolon and an incorect use of ``` else```

Comment: Semicolons are missing after 2 `return`s in `search` function. The `else` used in `search` is invalid because it is corresponding not to `if` but to `for`.

Comment: Also couldn't reproduce on [CS50 IDE](https://ide.cs50.io/). [What I got](https://ideone.com/6bF4Kn)

Comment: thank you for your clear explanation of my error, fixt it and won't do it again. Especially for the else and my semicolon. thanks again

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other problems, this statement: `return` is missing the trailing semicolon `;`  Therefore, the posted code cannot possibly be what you are executing.

Comment: regarding: `typedef struct
{
    string name;
    string number;
}
person;`  always include a `tag` name for a struct.  'most' debuggers use the `tag` name to be able to access the fields of the struct.

Comment: regarding: `        string try_again = get_string("Would you like to search for a other person? (Y/N) : ");` and `if (strcmp(try_again, "Yes") == 0 || strcmp(try_again, "yes") == 0 || (int) try_again == 89 || (int) try_again == 121)`  The code asks for a 'Y' or a 'N'  not a string like 'yes'.   Suggest using `get_char()` wi format string: " %c"  (notice the leading space) and processing the returned char value with `#include <ctype.h>` and `tolower( returned char from call to `get_char() );` so only have to make a single comparison with `y`

Comment: regarding; `if (strcmp(try_again, "Yes") == 0 || strcmp(try_again, "yes") == 0 || (int) try_again == 89 || (int) try_again == 121)`  What if the user enters "YES" or if they follow the directions and only enter "Y"?

Comment: regarding: `sreach(count, people);` 1) the name of the function is: `search()` not `sreach()`.   2) since this is inside the function: `search()` this makes the function: `search()` recursive but there is no exit strategy so the whole logic will fail.

Comment: regarding; `else
    {
        repeat = 1;
    }`   How do you expect the code execution to ever get to this code block?

Comment: suggest moving all the 'do you want to retry' from the `search()` function, to the `main()` function

Comment: what happens if the only thing entered by the user is a '\n' in response to the call to `get_string()`?

Comment: regarding: `void search(int count, person people[])`  in general, this would be much better written as: `void search( int count, person people[ count ] )`  The added horizontal spacing for readability.  The second `count` to help the compiler.